# Esiste un equivalente del "Pirate-English" in italiano? Pirate-Italian?

Tags: english-comparison, history

Premesso che per equivalente non intendo un equivalente culturale come potrebbe essere il siciliano parlato dai mafiosi, nella cultura inglese c'è questo dialetto parlato dai pirati. Ora, io non so se in Italia ci fosse questa gran fioritura di pirati, ma sono curioso di come parlassero rispetto all'italiano corrente del tempo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non penso proprio che esista un analogo.

Prima di tutto non mi risulta che in Italia ci sia stata una tradizione di pirateria propriamente detta (la Wikipedia italiana, per quel che vale, ne conosce [tre di numero](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria:Pirati_italiani)). E poi, anche nel mondo anglosassone, il “pirate talk” è quasi del tutto [un'invenzione recente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Talk_Like_a_Pirate_Day#Linguistic_background), soprattutto cinematografica, a partire dai primi film (sonori) tratti dall'*Isola del tesoro*.

Comment: Dal doppiaggio di quegli stessi film che citi abbiamo peró un sacco di espressioni in italiano standard che probabilmente nessun pirata ha mai proferito: i vari "arrrrr, brutti cani", "seguitemi, ciurmaglia", "affé mia, vi daró in pasto ai pesci". Una solta di "pirate doppiaggese"?